# How does an empty list work to initialize a QApplication object?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm new to python and PyQt. When I studyting how to code with PyQt5, I see many people initialize the QApplication object in such way:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
```

It's legal, but how do I realize it?

I guess that its because the paraments of QApplication() is like (argc, **argv), so an empty list is useful to make a default initialization. But I dont really know how the class works.
May I just use QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) to avoid any trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QAplication` takes a list as a positional argument, so it won't work without it. That list can contain additional instructions like `[-style, fusion]`, but QApplication will run fine without additional instructions (empty list).

The 'proper' way to initialise QApplication is:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

That way any  arguments that were used to start the program are passed on to QApplication.

The empty list you're seeing is probably from people providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  When the problem at hand doesn't have anything to do with arguments for QApplication, you can just use an empty list.